# Is a repeated measures t-test appropriate for this scenario?

Tags: r, t-test, repeated-measures

I am working with a dataset that involves participants taking a baseline test and a post-test. The company I am working with has the mean baseline score for participants from a year ago, and they would like me to run a repeated measures t-test using the old baseline score means. There are now new participants who have taken a post-test, but no baseline test (which is where the means come in.) Basically, the data is structured as so:

[image: A dataset containing three columns, one for participant ID, one for the post-test score, and one for the baseline score. The baseline score is the same for each participant.]

Because of this, the standard deviation for the Baseline scores is zero. Can I still run a repeated measures t-test on this dataset? Is there a better-suited test I should be running? I cannot share the dataset because the company has asked me not to share it. In case this helps, I am using R for data analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you mean by a "repeated measures" t test in this situation.
The terminology "repeated measures" has been used so carelessly in so many
different contexts that it has become meaningless.

If you have a baseline test and a post test for for each subject and if the differences between baseline and post test are normally distributed, then you need
a paired t test. In that case, a paired t test amounts to a one-sample t test on
the differences with the hull hypothesis being $0$ difference on average.

If you are comparing normally distributed 'post-test' scores with an average from previous years (presumably for a population of subjects that is comparable with the current ones), then you need a one-sample t test with the established mean from pervious years as the hypothetical value.

If you are permitted to give a clearer description of (a) whom you have tested and under what circumstances and (b) what you want to find out from your data, then maybe
one of us can be of more help.